# Working with multiple multiple elements

Tags: matlab, trigonometry, element

Say I had `y=sin(x)` where x is made up of multiple elements, say `x=(1:1:5)`.

How do I solve for all elements in a variable z where all I know is `z=cos(y)` using just MATLAB code, no algebraic manipulation?

Answer (score 2):

```
z=cos(sin(x))
```

Also `x=1:5` is enough, no need for increment when it is one

Comment: Correct in principle, but please remove the dot to make the code actually runnable in MATLAB.

Comment: Oh, dot was a typo. Thanks.